# overflow with z-index

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML markup

```
<div id="main">
 <div id="div1" style="position:relative;"></div>
 <div id="div2" style="z-index:-1; position:relative; overflow:auto; height:500px;"></div> 
</div>
```

In `div2` I load data dynamically and the content could exceed the divs height, so I used a `overflow:auto` property to show a scrollbar. The problem is that the scrollbar appears in all browsers, but it is working just in IE8/9, FireFox and Chrome. In other browsers you see 
the scrollbar, but without functionality.

Comment: still looking for answer if there is One!

Answer (score 3):

Your div2 has z-index of -1.  So it is behind. That's why it does not work.

Comment: Drop that z-index. Whydo you have it anyway?

Comment: z-index propert is necessary in my layout

Comment: I think z-index is the reason. Try to drop it and look, if the problem is so solved. If it breaks your layout, you'll have to find a different approach to the layout.

Comment: this is indeed the solution. You are covering the scrollbars with another object.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found that the negative z-index was indeed the problem and that a positive z-index was the solution. Try setting the z-index of div2 to 0 or some positive value X and then set the z-index of your other elements to a z-index that's greater than 0 or X. A negative z-index causes an item to be "below" the level of mouse interaction, thus the new z-indicies will cause div2 to be behind other content with a higher z-index while still allowing for mouse interaction.

See this question for more detail: 
[Weird z-index behaviour preventing mouse interactions: bug or normal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024854/weird-z-index-behaviour-preventing-mouse-interactions-bug-or-normal)